# Core Data - Managed object question

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have 2 basic questions regarding Core Data;

1. What exactly is a managed object -- Is it equivalent to 1 instance of a class. For example, if there is an entity called Shape which has attributes like no of sides & color and if there are 5 entries displayed in a table, does it mean there are 5 managed objects each with attributes no. of sides & color. I am a bit confused about this basic concept.
2. What exactly is the relationship between Fetched Results Controller (FRC) and a table view? I know the delegate methods, but how exactly is the table view impacted/related to FRC ?

Any basic examples will be really useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. A managed object is a representation of some entity that has been persisted by an application.  It is simply a generic abstraction away from the actual persisted type.  So you are right in saying that the managed object will have the same keys/properties as the concrete type.  As the NSManagedbject class implements the key-value coding pattern you can query its key/values at runtime...

```
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
```

For full documentation on NSManagedObject see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/valueForKey%3a)

Q2. The fetched results controller is what your UIViewController is to your UIView.  It contains the logic that controls persistence for your table view.  Its sole purpose in life is to keep database handling logic out of your UITableView.  It does so by allowing you to define the behaviour you want to execute in the context of your UITableView.  What I mean by this is that its delegate provides methods with signatures that explicitly imply an effect on a UITableView.

Comment: Could you please explain in simpler terms. I am not a very advanced Obj-C user.

Comment: Every time you fetch "entities" out the persistent store you need a way access their attributes. An NSManagedObject is just a wrapper for a single "entity"s data. It allows you to access it's attributes with valueForKey: and setValue:forKey:.

I find it easy to think of NSManagedObjects as a sort of interface masked over the currently fetched entities that allows me to work with them like a "normal" object.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Yes, there are 5 managed objects out there and available to you. You could put all five in an array if you wanted to. Managed Object is simply a term that means you have code to manage the Insert, Change, and Delete actions into the database - in otherwords, some code manages it through its life cycle. You get at it through an FRC, the FRC ^fetches^ instances of the object from the database, and allows your code to ^control^ what happens to the ^result^. Hence the name.